# Height of lighthouse based on angle difference

Tags: trigonometry

I have a question in my maths book: A lookout in a lighthouse tower can see two ships approaching the coast. Their angles of depression are 25° and 30°. If the ships are 100 m apart, show that the height of the lighthouse, to the nearest metre, is 242 metres. I have no clue how to solve it, please can someone give me a step-by-step process of how to work it out??

Comment: Let the height of the lighthouse be say, h. Can you express the distance of the ships away from the base of the lighthouse in terms of h? The difference of the distances is equal to 100m.

Comment: The far ship is L+100m away from the base of the cliff, the closer ship is L metres away. That's all I can get from the question

Comment: Try to get L in terms of h using the basic definitions of sin, cos, tan. Can you find the angle of elevation to the top of the lighthouse from the ship instead?

Comment: I don't know how to find L unfortunately. The angle of elevation from the far ship is 60 degrees and from the closer ship it is 65 degrees

Comment: The angles of depression and elevation are alternate interior angles, so they should be equal.  A $242~\text{m}$ light house is as tall as an $80$ story building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

HERE LET AB=H (HEIGHT OF LIGHTHOUSE)
Here lets apply trigonometry in $\triangle ABC$
$$tan\angle ACB=\frac{AB}{BC}$$
$$tan30=\frac{AB}{x}$$
$$\rightarrow AB=H=tan30(x)\tag1$$

Applying the same thing in $\triangle ABD$ we can get
$$tan\angle ADB=\frac{AB}{100+x}$$
$$tan25=\frac{AB}{100+x}$$
$$\rightarrow AB=H=tan25(100+x)\tag2$$

As $(1)=(2)$
We can easily get 
$$x=420.09m\tag3$$ using $tan25=0.466$ and $tan30=0.577$

Now again coming back to $\triangle ABC$ and using equation $(1)$
$$H=420.09(tan30)$$ 
$$H=242.5m \sim 242m$$

Answer (score 0):

*Let x be the height of the lighthouse, let d be the distance between the first boat and the base of the lighthouse*

To begin, using the fact that we know 'x' will be the same for both triangles created. Using basic trigonometry, we come to the point where x = d/tan(60) = (d+100)/tan(65)

**From this we begin to find x:** *Note: bolded italics is an explanation of what is occurring*

d⋅tan(65) = (d+100)⋅tan(60)

d⋅tan(65) = (d+100)⋅√(3) ***[tan(60)=√(3)]***

d⋅tan(65) = d√(3) + 100√(3) ***[Expand brackets]***

d⋅tan(65) - d√(3) =  100√(3) ***[- d√(3)]***

d (tan(65) - √(3)) = 100√(3) ***[Factor d]***

d = 100√(3) / (tan(65) - √(3)) ***[/tan(65) - √(3)]***

d ≈ 419.94m

**Now knowing what the distance from base of lighthouse to first ship is, we can calculate the height using trigonometry**

tan(60)= 419.94 / x

x = 419.94 / tan(60)

x ≈ 242.45m

*In the same fashion:*

tan(65)= (419.94 + 100) / x

x = 519.94 / tan(65)

x ≈ 242.45m

**∴ The height of the lighthouse is 242.45m**

Comment: I had this question for a maths problem so I uploaded my work here because it coincided when I was doing my research to see any possible routes for a solution, sorry for not using MathJax (will use next time) but I feel my answer gives a bit more understanding compared to the first one. It was just a coincidence I saw this and put in my answer \_(シ)_/